# VBS in html wont work?

Tags: html, vbscript, hta

I created this as a HTA file and now I want to change it to HTML page. I thought I can only remove `<HTML APPLICATION....>` and paste rest of stuff into a html file. But looks like it wont work that way....

What this HTA does is that allows user to enter information and save it to a text file then call up another batch file to run rest of work. It works in HTA but I have issues with user permission to write info back to the text file on server. so I want to do it on the webpage.

Can anyone tell me how can I make this page work?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Files Sync </title>
</head>

<script language="vbscript">

Sub WriteTxt_OnClick()
    Dim fso, txt

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set txt = fso.CreateTextFile("E:\Temp\000.txt")

    txt.WriteLine document.Submitted_Link_To_Mex.body.value

    MsgBox ("File Submitted")

End Sub

Sub SYNC_onClick

     Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
     WshShell.Run "E:\Temp\hahaha.bat", 0
            ' 0 => hide
     MsgBox("Success")

End Sub
</script>

<H2>Copy And Paste The Folder Path To Here </H2>
<body>

<form name="Submitted_Link_To_Mex">
<textarea name="body" cols="150" rows="20">

</textarea>
</form>

<br>
    <input type="button" value="1. SUBMIT" name="WriteTxt"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input type="Button" value="2. SYNC" name="SYNC"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input type="Button" value="3. CLOSE" name="button2" onClick="close">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: VBS only works in IE.

Comment: yes, we are only allowed to use IE.....sad

Comment: You won't be allowed to execute a batch file on the server through IIS. Why not convert this to a .NET web page?

Comment: I dont know .NET at all......

Comment: vbs is not supported in IE11 for Internet web pages. Use compatability view. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn384057(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: good to know, we still on IE 10

Answer (score 3):

I realize this post is two years old, but I had a similar problem, and was unable to find a solution after hours of googling how to use VBS in an HTA application. For the sake of others who might have this issue in the future, I have found out that putting the following code in the header will allow the use of VBS in HTA applications.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">
```

It won't work for later versions of IE. Only IE 10 and older.

Answer (score 0):

The browser is a program on your computer that does what arbitrary servers all around the world do tell it. It stands to reason that the capabilites of such an agent of foreign powers have to be restricted.

A HTA is a program you installed on your computer (because you made sure you can trust it). It is executed by mshta.exe, not your browser (although both certainly share code). Such a program can do what you do on your machine.

So you can't do what you want to do.